# Display random single survey poll in side bar, show results, next poll?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We're developing an app in Rails, and want to randomly display a question to users that they haven't seen yet. Once they answer, it would show the results, and then ask if they want to answer the next question.

Has anyone done this? Is there perhaps some kind of gem that can help us, or do we have to write it from scratch?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the randumb gem for something similar.  With it you can use scopes to chain your queries so you could fetch only an un_seen record (and subsequently update it to seen)

https://github.com/spilliton/randumb